# Multiple await in single async function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to connect to to db then run my server. So I am using aync await like below:

```
  startApp = async()=>{
  try {
        await mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://tanvirgeek:<password>@cluster0-e7kwf.mongodb.net/test? 
     retryWrites=true&w=majority',)
        console.log('connected to db');
        await app.listen(5000);
        console.log('server connected on port 5000')
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send("hello world");
})

startApp();
```

I intentionally gave a wrong db connect URL without a password to get error in the console. In the console I am getting no error and this message:`server connected on port 5000`. 
My desired output is error message in the console, without this successful server running message. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't know why `mongoose.connect()` isn't reject its promise, but `app.listen(5000)` does NOT return a promise so the `await` there does nothing useful.  I guess you can do `let result = mongoose.connect()` and see if `result` is actually a promise?

Comment: how can I see if result is a promise? By logging result?

Comment: Yes, just `console.log(result);`.  You can also always check if it has a `.then()` method.  `if (typeof result.then === "function")`.

Answer (score 0):

you are adding a ',' between your path connection and ')'. In mongoose doc:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://tanvirgeek:<password>@cluster0-e7kwf.mongodb.net/test? 
 retryWrites=true&w=majority', { useNewUrlParser: true }).
  catch(error => handleError(error));

// Or:
try {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://tanvirgeek:<password>@cluster0-e7kwf.mongodb.net/test? 
 retryWrites=true&w=majority', { useNewUrlParser: true });
} catch (error) {
  handleError(error);
}
```

source [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#error-handling)